# Facebook OAuth issue? Infinite loop changing "state" parameter on URL

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

Our app was working fine but, without any change on our side, when we tried to enter our Facebook app outside the canvas (directly on http://example.herokuapp.com), and after providing our FB user and password, we are stuck in an infinite loop where the "state" parameter on the URL is constantly changing:

```
https://example.herokuapp.com/?state=05b40a2e4d2c1f7b4c13a026a069acc3&code=AQCql520w_5dJjHnJlojMvzSCukAMrRsjqCipdkDP3N4h4zUQH72Q79oH2EMd_tQDv-fwKTJr2LG-azBUt37bUX06r3t9QHBwb27XBQyxmgdGdR_A1flZBY_oP-L0UEhjSu1FE8v2blILC8EuEWLNikgtkmaWWwy9e93KQX00wiVj422pzHuzn-m9_jZEUiKsf3dQIwCE3V7UBHMZCD9gS0#_=_
```

Inside the FB canvas it is working fine. And we have a twin app (test environment) that is working fine inside and outside the canvas (same code and configuration).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you using javascript sdk to handle the user status?

Comment: did you try to delete your cookie and try again ? also note that heroku app may switch storage/server at the backend, any state data stored on disk may be destroyed, so make sure you use a "shared session".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did post that question twice, and added a bounty to both of them.. That is weird :P

[Facebook app on infinite loop trying to log in out of canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965133/facebook-app-on-infinite-loop-trying-to-log-in-out-of-canvas/16040524)

As I already answered, someone had the same problem and made a blog post on it :

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/facebook-apps-infinite-redirection-solution/

Might be a configuration problem.

Try updating your sdk too.

Clear cache and cookies.