# Facebook app on infinite loop trying to log in out of canvas

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, openid, facebook-oauth

When I try to access to my app from http://apps.facebook.com/myapp (FB canvas) it is working fine. However, if I do directly from http://myapp.herokuapp.com (out of canvas), after entering my FB credentials, it is stuck in a loop where the URL parameters "state" and "code" are changing constantly.

In the FB app configuration, the canvas URL and the site URL are both http://myapp.herokuapp.com.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone had the same problem and made a blog post on it :

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/facebook-apps-infinite-redirection-solution/

Might be a configuration problem.

Try updating your sdk too.

Clear cache and cookies.